# How to display only the last 3 rows value of my ACF repeater

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

[user posted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuDvx.png)

How to display only the last 3 rows value of my ACF repeater fields.

Answer (score 1):

Repeater it's just array.

```
$repeater = get_field('repeater');
foreach( $repeater as $key => $row ) {
    if ( $key < 3 ) {
        var_dump($row);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```